# How to align right-to-left the elements of css menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

```
I am looking at this example of a only css generated drop down menu:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/7/

And I was wondering how can I make the items under the "About us" tab to be aligned from right to left.Now they look like that:

```
   About us
   |Menu items with different length|
```

I want it to look like that:

```
                             About us
   |Menu items with different length|
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/966/)**

**css**

```
li ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: I'll do it.Can I ask you why when I change right to 1, -1  etc. it is always the same?And when I set it to 0 it is exactly what I want.What is meaning of right:0 ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik only 0 can be written without a unit. use `-1px` or `1px` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `right:0;` to `li:hover ul` or to `li ul`

```
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

[**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/XPE3w/965/)

Answer (score 0):

use the `float:right` in your css style.

```
li ul {
display: none;
position:absolute;
float:right;
}
```